# please upgrade your tensorflow 1.4 error comes up but TF 1.4 already installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm trying to run object detection API's object_detection_tutorial.ipynb and I was able to run it before and i trained some simple models for object detection. I think broke my installation. I'm using Anaconda+Windows and Tensorflow 1.4 installed on an environment called "neuralnets" here is pip list of this environment:
[pip list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv9eK.jpg)
error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUUBG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

if in your Python console you type:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__Version__
```

What do you get? just to make sure try to reinstall with the `--ignore-installed` flag:

`pip install --ignore-installed tensorflow=1.4`

Comment: Thanks it's working now , i didn't use pip much, i have to look into it more i think.